# JSONCPP Build with Visual Studio 2010

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, jsoncpp

How do I build it? The documentation is really shady about this. It says you need to place scons.py into the directory, but I have no idea where this is. I have tried using the included prebuild, but it did not produce any .lib files.

Answer (score 17):

No need to use scons.

After you download the jsoncpp source, like from https://github.com/mrtazz/json-cpp, unzip the sources. In this unzipped source tree, under /makefiles/vc71/ you will find several Visual Studio project files which you can up convert and build.

Comment: You can also use the new Amalgamated version of jsoncpp. No libraries required; you just add a few files directly to your project and compile them in with the rest of your code.

Answer (score 1):

There is a visual studio solution file under makefiles. Did you try migrating that to VS2010 to see if it works?

Comment: Yes I have, and when I build it under debug and release it doesn't create any .libs.

Answer (score -5):

.py? This is a python script, and has nothing to do with C++. Perhaps you are looking at the wrong instructions.